# Unique key related problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very confused in difference between unique key and primary key, and unique key constraint and primary key constraint in SQL Server.

Can I define more than 1 primary key in my table?

Again I am not getting how to set unique key in my table and what is the practical use of it. Second thing, I found statement like this on internet

> A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint
>   defined on it.
>
> Note that you can have many UNIQUE constraints per table, but only one
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint per table.

Does it mean that when I create primary key, it automatically define the unique key on that, that is I can have only 1 null value inserted in it?

Answer (score 4):

your primary key is always unique. you can add additional keys and the may or may not be unique. If i am not wrong, the primary key decides how the records are actually stored on the disk.

Comment: By *default*, the primary key will also be the clustered index for the table. This is the index that contains all of the column data in its leaves. It doesn't guarantee any actual ordering of data on the disk.

Comment: ...or the order in which data is returned by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have more than one primary key on a table, but you can have as many (within reasonable technical limits) unique constraints on a table.

The primary key cannot contain nulls, a unique constraint does allow nulls to occur, but treats NULLs as values in this case (so for a single column constraint, only one null value can occur).

Both Primary Keys and Unique constraints may be the referenced key for a foreign key constraint.

---

Many relational purists believe that the introduction of "Primary Key" in SQL was a mistake - there's no real reason to select one key as "better" than any other key - if there are genuinely multiple keys for the table. You could abandon primary keys entirely and only use UNIQUE constraints, and treat all keys equally.

Comment: Interesting secondary comment. If a relation contains multiple candidate keys however, can we assume that the relation is therefore not fully Normalized?

Comment: @John Samsom - how about a table of chemical elements? They have unique names, unique symbols, unique atomic numbers. Each of these is a candidate key.

Comment: Or a table of countries - again, they have unique names, unique 2 letter codes, unique 3 letter codes. Each of these is a candidate key.

Answer (score 1):

Ok:

- you can have **only one** primary key for each table
- the primary key is by definition **unique** and does **not allow NULL** values

On the other hand:

- you can define **as many** unique indices as you like

The **primary key** is a very special thing - it defines the way to clearly and uniquely identify each row. Therefore it **must** be unique, and it **cannot** be NULL.

The unique index is just that - a mechanism to ensure something (a column, several columns toegther) are unique. You can have multiple of those constraints on a table.

Each unique index *could be* your primary key - it's a so-called candidate key. But only one of those can be picked and chosen to actually be your primary key.

Comment: This statement is contradictory, a unique key can be treated as primary key, but primary key don't allow null. "Each unique index could be your primary key - it's a so-called candidate key. But only one of those can be picked and chosen to actually be your primary key."

Comment: you mean to say that each primary key is unique key then i learnt that  primary key allows not null, but unique allows null, how come?

Comment: @NoviceDotNet: each unique key **could** be your primary key, and if you pick it as your primary key, it also **cannot** allow NULLs - no contradiction at all

Comment: ok, got it, need to think little more on it, if find any query, i'll post soon.

Comment: @NoviceDotNet: UNIQUE KEY means UNIQUE - PRIMARY KEY means UNIQUE **AND** NOT NULL

Comment: and what does unique constraint meaning, is it different from unique key?

Comment: @NoviceDotNet: you can have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on a single column, or you can define a `UNIQUE INDEX` on one or multiple columns - they both basically mean the same thing: no duplicates allowed.

Comment: @marc_s: A primary key is a candidate key and a candidate key is a _minimal superkey_. Therefore only minimal unique keys should be usable as primary key, no?